# Unterminated Delimeter in sed Command While Passing a Variable

Tags: perl, nginx, sed

I've been struggling with this for more than an hour now and I'm not sure what's wrong. Using Perl, I'm trying to use sed to do an in-line replacement of a string in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf as noted by using  the sed command below:

```
my $replacement_string = getstringforreplace();
my $command = qq ( sudo sed -i "s~default_type        application/octet-stream;~default_type        application/octet-stream;$replacement_string~" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf );
system ( $command );
die ( $command ); # Using this for debugging purposes.
```

I'm really trying to place the $replacement_string after matching that 'default type' line in nginx.conf but I'm not sure what to use besides sed.

I've (1) changed the delimiters to avoid any issues with the forward slashes, (2) double quoted the replacement (I'm really not sure why, I was using single quotes before), and (3) removed a newline character I had right before the $replacement_string, among other things.

I went ahead and put the *die ( $command );* in there as noted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968056/unterminated-s-command) answer, but I'm not seeing what's wrong. This is what that returns -- which is pretty much what I want:

```
sudo sed -i "s~default_type        application/octet-stream;~default_type        application/octet-stream;
# Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
# See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
# for more information.
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    tserver_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
~" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

The $replacement_string is returned by the call to the subroutine getstringforreplace() below:

```
sub getstringforreplace
{
    my $message = qq (
    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        tserver_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
    );
    return $message;
}
```

Any guidance would be really appreciated as I'm not sure how to get rid of this *unterminated `s' command* issue. I'm thinking now it has to do with that qq() from the subroutine I'm calling.

Comment: `sed` doesn't like newlines in the replacement literal.

Comment: Are you trying to match an entire line in `nginx.conf`?

Comment: @Beta Yes, although I'm really trying to match whatever is necessary to insert the $replacement_string right after that line in nginx.conf.

Comment: Then may I suggest writing the replacement string to a file and then using sed's 'r' (read) command?

Comment: I thought about that initially but I'm trying to avoid creating a separate file just for that. I just really want to find out how to insert a block of lines with new lines,etc., without taking the file approach. I'll try to see if what @ikegami suggested helps, otherwise I might just take your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Beta's comments above I was able to obtain the result I wanted. It involved:

1. changing the subroutine getstringforreplace() to print the contents of qq() to a temporary file,
2. doing an in-place replacement using sed to read the contents of that file into /etc/nginx/nginx.conf,
3. and then removing the temporary file.

...which is below:

```
getstringforreplace(); # Prints $replacement_string to temp.txt.
my $command = qq ( sudo sed -i -e '/octet-stream;/r temp.txt' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf );
system ( $command );
system ( 'sudo rm temp.txt' );
```

Ideally, I would have liked to not have to print to a file, etc., but for the moment this yields the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` doesn't like newlines in the replacement literal.

```
$ sed 's~a~b~' /dev/null

$ sed 's~a~b
~' /dev/null
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unterminated `s' command
```

It does accept `\n`, so you could replace the newlines with `\n`. Of course, you could simply do the work in Perl. This will help you address a number of other issues:

- Shell command injection bug.
- Lack of escaping `\` in the replacement literal.
- Lack of error detecting and handling.